# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot add property __indexColor, object is not extensible

Tags: reactjs, neo4j, rtk-query

I am getting this error when I fetch the data from the backend using `rtk` query and loaded it into react force graph 2d. But when I copy the response data from the network tab and loaded the data into react force graph it is working fine.

```
{graphData && (
    <ForceGraph2D
        width={window.innerWidth}
        height={650}
        nodeRelSize={10}
        cooldownTicks={50}
        nodeCanvasObjectMode={() => 'after'}
        graphData={graphData}
        ref={forceRef}
        nodeCanvasObject={(node, ctx, globalScale) => {
            const label = node.name;
            const fontSize = globalScale * 1.2;
            ctx.font = `${fontSize}px Sans-Serif`;
            ctx.textAlign = 'center';
            ctx.textBaseline = 'middle';
            ctx.fillStyle = node.isClusterNode ? 'white' : 'black'; //node.color;
            const lineHeight = fontSize * 1.2;
            const x = node.x ?? 0;
            const y = node.y ?? 0 - lineHeight;
            ctx.fillText(label, x, y);
        }}
        onNodeClick={handleNodeClick}
    />
)}
```

I am calling react force graph like this.
graph data is coming from `rtk` query get API.

[image]

Comment: So what is the error?

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot add property __indexColor, object is not extensible

Comment: Can you share a screenshot or the complete text of the error message?

Answer (score 1):

Solved the issue by assigning the node and link data into different variable
const nodes = graphDatas.nodes.map((item: any) => Object.assign({}, item));
const links = graphDatas.links.map((item: any) => Object.assign({}, item));

```
 <ForceGraph2D
    width={window.innerWidth}
    height={650}
    nodeRelSize={10}
    cooldownTicks={50}
    nodeCanvasObjectMode={() => 'after'}
    graphData={{nodes,links}}
    ref={forceRef}
    nodeCanvasObject={(node, ctx, globalScale) => {
        const label = node.name;
        const fontSize = globalScale * 1.2;
        ctx.font = `${fontSize}px Sans-Serif`;
        ctx.textAlign = 'center';
        ctx.textBaseline = 'middle';
        ctx.fillStyle = node.isClusterNode ? 'white' : 'black'; //node.color;
        const lineHeight = fontSize * 1.2;
        const x = node.x ?? 0;
        const y = node.y ?? 0 - lineHeight;
        ctx.fillText(label, x, y);
    }}
    onNodeClick={handleNodeClick}
/>
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and solved it by creating a new object with spread operator as @Aneesh mentioned.

```js
<ForceGraph2D
  graphData={{
    nodes: nodes.map((x) => ({ ...x })),
    links: links.map((x) => ({ ...x }))
  }}
</ForceGraph2D>
```